# bootstrap date picker clear value

Tags: datepicker

I have two dates, Start date and End date. 
I need to validate the the end date should not greater than the start date.

need to clear (previous start date value) the date value when ever we change the date.

- case 1# [ First time]
  start date - 23-Nov-2013
  End date - 24-Nov-2013

now i changed the start date as -25-Nov-2013, but end date enabled the  the 24-Nov-2013 (start previous value) on wards instead of 26-Nov-203.

So, i need to clear the value when ever i change the date.

Comment: can you add your code?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what that 27/11/2013 represents is the current Date. Which will not get updated *unless you write it on **`changeDate`** event.*

So you have to do like

1. Bind the `start date`, with **`changeDate`** event.
2. Increment the selected date in start.
3. Again set back the incremented date.
4. Now update this to `end Date` using **`update`** method

   `$('#end').datepicker('update', toDate)`;

Finally, you code will be like

```
$('#start').datepicker({}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    var toDate = ev.date;
    toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() + 1);
    $('#end').datepicker('update', toDate);
});
$('#end').datepicker({});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/GX82L/3/)