# Daterange Picker open end when closing start

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to use [bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/), got it working, now there are some usability issue left.

Is it possible the open the second datepicker in a daterange when closing the first one? I am not really good in js. would be great if anyone could help here..[Link to Demo](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=range&format=dd.mm.yyyy&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=de&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&todayHighlight=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="start" />
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="end" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
         format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
         language: "de",
         todayHighlight: true
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further investigation, I found myself that I messed it with jQuery datepicker.

Here in `Bootstrap datepicker`, there is no method like `onClose()` but using **`changeDate`** you can simply accomplish the issue.

```
$('#start').datepicker({
    autoclose: true  // This enable you to close the picker
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    $("#end").focus();
});
$('#end').datepicker();
```

**FYI:** To close your picker, you make use of [**`autoclose`**](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search.html?q=autoclose&check_keywords=yes&area=default) property in bootstrap datepicker.

Here is a simple [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/GX82L/10/) for you.

Comment: @ChrisWe You're welcome :) I have added more details to it with updated fiddle, take a look.

Comment: Do you have any Idea how to highlight the dates in between without selecting the end date first?

Comment: @ChrisWe Yes possible.  You can set value to the datepicker.  Here you can check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20236642/1671639)